# Django Sites - Different urls.py for two sites

Tags: django, django-urls, django-sites

I maintain a Django webapp for a client of mine. We built it out in Django and for computer users, it's great. We now want to cater to mobile device users.

On top of a template switch, we also need things to work differently. The application will have views that work in a subtly different way but also the URL structure needs to be simplified.

I realise what I'm about to ask for violates the DRY ethos but is there a good way to split the `urls.py` so that half of it is for `ourdomain.com` and the other half is for `m.ourdomain.com`? If I can do that, I can add a `mobile_views.py` and write the new views.

Django's Sites is enabled in the project but I'm happy to use a hard-coded `request.domain.startswith('m.')`-style hack. Seems like that might perform better - but I've no idea how one gets the request from the URLs file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/middleware/#process_request) to detect the access to the other site and set [`request.urlconf`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.urlconf) to the other urlconf that you want to use.

Comment: Yeah that'll work for me. Thanks. Edit: I assume this has to be one of the first middleware rules to trigger. And do you know if Django's `reverse` will still work (assuming the new URLs have the same names)?

Comment: You may have to pass `request.urlconf` to [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse), but otherwise it should work.